# Read Text File by column and create 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

How do I read the below text file by column, and find the min value for the grade array by column? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

This is my text file

```
John  25 5 4.5 5 4 5 10 10 6 9.5 5.5
Jim   25 5 4 5 4.5 5 10 4 10 9.5 7.5
Kathy 15 1 3 2 1 1.5 8 2 4 3 4
Steve 21 5 3 2 1 4 5 6 7 8 8
Stacy 15 5 1 1 1 5 3 8 9 5 7
Faith 16 3 4 2 4 4 7 5 2 3 8
```

This is what I want the array to look like

```
Name = John, Jim, Kathy, Steve, Stacy, Faith
grade1 = 25 25 15 21 15 16
grade2 = 5 5 1 5 5 3
grade3 = 4.5 4 3 3 1 4
```

and so on ....

This is my code

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter writer =  new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Output.txt"));

    double[][] grades = null;

    findMinIndex(grades); //I call the function here just to test out my result before print out to text file.

     writer.println("Min: " + findMinIndex(grades));
     writer.close();
}
```

//This method to read the file -- have to add this part or the page wont' let me save my code --

```
public static void processSection(PrintWriter writer, double[][]grades, String[] names) throws IOException
{
{
    Scanner in  = null;

    try
    {
        in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));         

        //in.nextLine();

          int rows = in.nextInt();
          int columns = in.nextInt();             
          grades = new double[rows][columns];             
          names = new String[grades.length];    
          String[] col = null;

          while(in.hasNextLine()) 
          {     
              for (int i=0; i< grades.length; i++)
              {
                  col = in.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");     

                  for (int j = 1; j < col.length; j++)                     
                  {                              
                      names[i] = col[0];

                      grades[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(col[j]);

                  }   
              }         
          }  

         in.close();     
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

}

//This method to find Min
public static double findMinIndex(double[][] grades) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{       
        double min = grades[0][0];  

        for (int j = 0; j < grades.length; j++) 
        {
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for (int i = 1; i < grades[j].length; i++) 
            {                                       
                if (grades[j][i] < min) 
                {                   
                    min = grades[j][i];                      
                }
            }               
        }

        System.out.println(min);
        return min;
}

//The result I got is to calculate the min by the row not by the column.
```

Comment: *"This is my text file.."* What is your question?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson -- my question is above that statement :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson --
I want to read the text file by column, and find the min value for the grade array by column.

Comment: That's a statement, not a question. For example, questions might be.. *"How do I implement this?"*, or *"Can you help me?"* or *"Is reading a text file by column possible, and if so, how?"* .. Note how each of those statements invites a reply, and ends with a ***?*** (question mark)! Note also that 2 out of three of those questions (the first two) are far too vague and broad for answering by SO. So .. again, ignore your specification or requirement, and tell us: What is your ***question?***

Comment: @Andrew Thompson --ahh... now when I go back in to modify my question, the page won't let me save again, keep telling me I have more code then details. How do I get pass that to be able to save my post? Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson-- I fixed it. I opened the edited post, and edit that one instead of the original one. Thanks

Comment: Congrats on figuring out the editing! *"How do I read the below text file by column,..?"* Ah. That's an interesting question. But it's actually not possible to do that with a text file unless each row (or line) in the text file has exactly the same size on disk - a [fixed width data file](http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-XLS/Features/Fixed-Width-Text-File-Definition.htm). That data appears **not to be** a FWTF. If it was it would pad each column of figures to be aligned (vertically) with the previous row. **Given it's not fixed width** the only realistic alternative is to first ..

Comment: .. read the file line by line, then split each line into the values. Those values might then be all put in an array that allows 'data access by column', but only **after** the file has been read line-by-line & broken into columns..

Comment: @Andrew Thompson -- my current code is already read the file line by line, and split the line. Then my question now is how do I put all those into an array that can be access by column? Thanks

Comment: @thi Is this question still open and unanswered? are you still working on this java program?

Comment: @davedwards - the question doesn't have an answer yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Create2DArray {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
        String[] names = getNames();
        List namesArrayList = Arrays.asList(names);
        String stringNames = namesArrayList.toString()
                .replace("[", "")
                .replace("]", "")
                .trim();         

        double[][] grades = getGrades();

        System.out.println("Name = " + stringNames);

        double rowsum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grades[0].length; i++) {
            System.out.print("grade" + (i+1) + " = ");
            for (int j = 0; j < grades.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(grades[j][i] + " ");
                rowsum += grades[j][i];
            }
            System.out.println("; Row sum = " + rowsum);
            rowsum = 0;
        }
    }

    private static String[] getNames() throws IOException {
        String[] names = null;

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        String line;
        int row = 0;
        int size = 0;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        int lines = 0;
        while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
        reader.close();

        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String name = line.trim().split("\\s+")[0];

            if (names == null) {
                size = lines;
                names = new String[size];
            }

            names[row] = name;
            row++;
        }
        return names;
    }

    private static double[][] getGrades() throws IOException {
        double[][] matrix = null;

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        String line;
        int nrows = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int ncols = 0;

        while (buffer.readLine() != null) nrows++;
        buffer.close();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] vals = line.trim().split("\\s+");
            ncols = vals.length-1;

            if (matrix == null) {
                matrix = new double[nrows][ncols];
            }

            for (int col = 1; col <= ncols; col++) {
                try {
                    matrix[row][col-1] = Double.parseDouble(vals[col]);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
            }
            row++;
        }
        reader.close();
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

output:

```
Name = John, Jim, Kathy, Steve, Stacy, Faith
grade1 = 25.0 25.0 15.0 21.0 15.0 16.0 ; Row sum = 117.0
grade2 = 5.0 5.0 1.0 5.0 5.0 3.0 ; Row sum = 24.0
grade3 = 4.5 4.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 4.0 ; Row sum = 19.5
grade4 = 5.0 5.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 ; Row sum = 17.0
grade5 = 4.0 4.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 4.0 ; Row sum = 15.5
grade6 = 5.0 5.0 1.5 4.0 5.0 4.0 ; Row sum = 24.5
grade7 = 10.0 10.0 8.0 5.0 3.0 7.0 ; Row sum = 43.0
grade8 = 10.0 4.0 2.0 6.0 8.0 5.0 ; Row sum = 35.0
grade9 = 6.0 10.0 4.0 7.0 9.0 2.0 ; Row sum = 38.0
grade10 = 9.5 9.5 3.0 8.0 5.0 3.0 ; Row sum = 38.0
grade11 = 5.5 7.5 4.0 8.0 7.0 8.0 ; Row sum = 40.0
```

Comment: @davewards - wow, finally, thank you very much. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: @davewards - I want to find min and max value for each grade row. thanks

Comment: @daveward - Thank you very much for your help. Ido you know why I can't sum up the columns. I want to sum each column separately, but the result keeps coming out as total of first column and keep adding on
My code to sum and calculate average:
double sum = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < grades[0].length; j++) 
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) 
    {           
        sum = sum + grades[i][j];    
    }  
    
    average = sum/grades[0].length;
}

This is the outcome:only the first column got correct number
Q1:
   Sum: 117.0
Q2:
   Sum: 141.0

Comment: Thanks but the result of the second row still add the result of the first row together, not separate(ex: second row sum = 24 not 141)
grade1 = 25.0 25.0 15.0 21.0 15.0 16.0 ; Row sum = 117.0
grade2 = 5.0 5.0 1.0 5.0 5.0 3.0 ; Row sum = 141.0
grade3 = 4.5 4.0 3.0 3.0 1.0 4.0 ; Row sum = 160.5

Comment: It's working. You are awesome, thank you so very much.

Comment: @davewards -- now I want to display the name with minimum value but I am able to display only 1 name. How can I display all the names that have the same minimum value? ex: grade1 has 2 people with 15, but I can only display 1. Thank you.

Comment: Sure I'll try to help. Can you please show your code that is only displaying 1 so far? So I can better understand, thanks.

Comment: the code is below
for (int i = 0; i < grades2[0].length; i++) 
{ min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  for (int j = 0; j < grades2.length; j++)
  {if (grades2[j][i] < min) 
   {  min = grades2[j][i];              
      name2Min = names2[j];}
   }
}
System.out.println ("  " + " Minimum: " + min + "\n");
         
System.out.println ("  " + name2Min + "\n");

Comment: @davewards
 for (int i = 0; i < grades2[0].length; i++) { min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; for (int j = 0; j < grades2.length; j++) {if (grades2[j][i] < min) { min = grades2[j][i]; name2Min = names2[j];} } } System.out.println (" " + " Minimum: " + min + "\n"); System.out.println (" " + name2Min + "\n");

Comment: Hey @Thi, here try this: `double[][] grades = getGrades();

        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double[] mins = new double[grades[0].length];

        for (int j = 0; j < grades[0].length; j++) {
            min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                if (grades[i][j] < min) {
                    min = grades[i][j];
                }
                mins[j] = min;
            }
        }`

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < grades[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Grade " + (j+1));
            for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                if (grades[i][j] == mins[j]) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + mins[j] + " " + names[i]);
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: it prints out all names who have the minimum value: `Grade 1
 15.0 Kathy
 15.0 Stacy
Grade 2
 1.0 Kathy
Grade 3
 1.0 Stacy
Grade 4
 1.0 Stacy
Grade 5
 1.0 Kathy
 1.0 Steve
 1.0 Stacy
Grade 6
 1.5 Kathy
Grade 7
 3.0 Stacy
Grade 8
 2.0 Kathy
Grade 9
 2.0 Faith
Grade 10
 3.0 Kathy
 3.0 Faith
Grade 11
 4.0 Kathy`

Comment: @davewards - I will try it out, and let you know. Thank you very much